# How to extract the part of filename with specific pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filenames

I'm looking to extract part of filename which I"m currently using position but it's not  working as desired output.

Sample data:

ls -a *0728*dat | sort

```
amnbmnbm_jnjmnm_sd_07282019_14_13_17.dat
amnbmnb_kjhkj_07282019_11_23_22.dat
njnkjnjk_AbnBCBB_DE_07282019_07_09_04.dat
```

I'm looking to extract the file part from the filename everything leftside from the date on wards including underscore(_) and assign it to vairable

Desired output:

variable file is something it needs to hold the values, so that I can pass in for loop

file:

```
amnbmnbm_jnjmnm_sd_
amnbmnb_kjhkj_
njnkjnjk_AbnBCBB_DE_


for file_name in "${file[@]}"
do

echo " file_name=$file_name"

done
```

Desired output:

```
amnbmnbm_jnjmnm_sd_
amnbmnb_kjhkj_
njnkjnjk_AbnBCBB_DE_
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
for file_name in *0728*dat
do
  printf '%s\n' "${file_name%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9].dat}"
done
```

This strips from the end of each filename the pattern of: 8 digits, underscore, 2 digits, underscore, 2 digits, underscore, 2 digits, then `.dat`.

Answer (score 0):

using sed:

```
ls -a *0728*dat | sed 's/[0-9].*//'
amnbmnb_kjhkj_
amnbmnbm_jnjmnm_sd_
njnkjnjk_AbnBCBB_DE_
```

or

```
ls -a *0728*dat | sed "s/[0-9]\{8\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}\.dat$//"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following requires `bash` 4.4 or newer, GNU `find` and GNU `sed` (or, at least a `find` and a `sed` that support NUL as the output/input separator):

```
$ mapfile -d '' files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*0728*.dat' -print0 | 
    sed -z 's:^\./::; s/[0-9][0-9_]\+.dat//')
```

This populates a bash array (`files`) with the matching filenames in the current directory after they've had the leading `./` and the date & time & .dat extension stripped by `sed`.   It uses NUL as the record (i.e. filename) separator to avoid any potential issues with spaces, line-feeds, shell meta-characters, etc in any of the filenames.

`find` is used because you should never use the output of `ls` as input to other programs or as arguments on another program's command-line - it is unsafe and unreliable.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

The `find` command can, of course, be modified to find files matching different patterns, or in sub-directories, etc.

Example:

```
$ touch amnbmnbm_jnjmnm_sd_07282019_14_13_17.dat amnbmnb_kjhkj_07282019_11_23_22.dat \
    njnkjnjk_AbnBCBB_DE_07282019_07_09_04.dat

$ mapfile -d '' files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*0728*.dat' -print0 | 
    sed -z 's:^\./::; s/[0-9][0-9_]\+.dat//')

$ typeset -p files
declare -a files=([0]="amnbmnbm_jnjmnm_sd_" [1]="amnbmnb_kjhkj_" [2]="njnkjnjk_AbnBCBB_DE_")

$ printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
amnbmnbm_jnjmnm_sd_
amnbmnb_kjhkj_
njnkjnjk_AbnBCBB_DE_
```